# How to import a .ipa file into Xcode for Development

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, ipa

I Have a debug build .ipa file. I want to perform some tests on Appium and I have to sign certificate using my developer account. Im planning to import the iPad file into Xcode to Change Build settings and bundle id, but I'm unable to import iPa file. Please provide suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert the .ipa file into an Xcode working set. You have to dig for you original code.

Comment: The Problem is, I'm testing the .ipa file i got from my development team when i launch the appium I can be able to see the app on the device/simulator but it crashes and log file says failed to create WDA session. so i wanna go through the build and check whats really happening.do you have any idea how to fix that ??

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not possible to install an IPA file to a simulator device. Even if you extract the APP file from the IPA file and try to install it on the simulator device, it won't.

For the simulator, you will need to generate an APP file that would be built specifically for that simulator. You will need the app source code to build the APP file.

2. Regarding the WebDriverAgent (WDA) issue that you are facing, know that if you are using Xcode version 14 and higher with Appium server version 1.22.3, then this combination won't work. Xcode 14 has broken the WebDriverAgent project (refer this defect: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/17904).

To fix this, you will need to use Appium server 2.0 which is still in Beta phase. Follow the Appium 2.0 guide here: https://appium.github.io/appium/docs/en/2.0/
Note: Please uninstall Appium 1.22.3 before installing Appium 2.0.